# Annotate Django queryset with previous Sunday based on row's date field

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, django-queryset

I have a table with a set of `Orders` that my customers made (purchased, to say so).

The customers can choose the delivery date. That value is stored in each `Order` in a field called `Order.delivery_date` (not too much inventive there)

```
class Order(BaseModel):
    customer = ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    delivery_date = DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to annotate a queryset that fetches `Orders` with the previous Sunday for that `delivery_date` (mostly to create a weekly report, "bucketized" per week)

I thought *"Oh! I know! I'll get the date index in the week and I'll subtract a `datetime.timedelta` with the number of days of that week index, and I'll use that to get the Sunday (like Python's .weekday() function)"*:

```
from server.models import *
import datetime
from django.db.models import F, DateField, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay

Order.objects.filter(
    delivery_date__isnull=False
).annotate(
    sunday=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('delivery_date') - datetime.timedelta(days=ExtractWeekDay(F('delivery_date')) + 1),
        output_field=DateField()
    )
).last().sunday
```

But if I do that, I get a `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: CombinedExpression` when trying to "construct": the `timedelta` expression.

Not using the `F` function in the `Extract` doesn't make a difference either: I get the same error regardless of whether I use `Extract(F('delivery_date'))` or `Extract('delivery_date')`

This is a Python 3.4, with Django 2.0.3 over MySQL 5.7.21

I know that I can always fetch the `Order` object and do this in Python (I even have a little helper function that would do this) but it'd be nice to fetch the objects with that annotation from the DB (and also for learning purposes)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have answered my own question, but if someone has a better suggestion, please feel free to answer.  
I'm not even too sure my answer is the best that can be done, and it certainly is very database specific. If someone has a more portable (more "Django-based" if you may) solution, please post it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I had forgotten about [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

It looks like this should do (at least for MySQL)

```
orders_q = Order.objects.filter(
    delivery_date__isnull=False
).extra(
    select={
        'sunday': "DATE_ADD(`delivery_date`, interval(1 - DAYOFWEEK(`delivery_date`)) DAY)"
    },
).order_by('-id')
```

It seems to work:

```
for record in orders_q.values('sunday', 'delivery_date'):
    print("date: {delivery_date}, sunday: {sunday} is_sunday?: {is_sunday}".format(
        is_sunday=record['sunday'].weekday() == 6, **record)
    )
```

---

```
date: 2018-06-04, sunday: 2018-06-03 is_sunday?: True
date: 2018-05-30, sunday: 2018-05-27 is_sunday?: True
date: 2018-05-21, sunday: 2018-05-20 is_sunday?: True
date: 2018-06-04, sunday: 2018-06-03 is_sunday?: True
```

**EDIT**: Apparently, `extra` is on its way to being deprecated/unsupported. At the very least, is not very... erm... [*fondly received*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/FojuU0syO8Y/discussion) by Django developers. Maybe it'd be better using [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) instead. Actually, I was having issues trying to do further filter in the `sunday` annotation using `extra` which I'm not getting with the `RawSQL` method..

This seems to work better:

```
orders_q = orders_q.annotate(
    sunday=RawSQL("DATE_ADD(`delivery_date`, interval(1 - DAYOFWEEK(`delivery_date`)) DAY)", ())
)
```

Which allows me to further annotate...

```
orders_q.annotate(sunday_count=Count('sunday'))
```

I'm not sure why, but when I was using `extra`, I'd get `Cannot resolve keyword 'sunday' into field`